# Investigating which Windows service is listening to which IP and port

Tags: windows-services

I am investigating a production system where there are several Windows services communicating with each other through TCP/IP sockets. I'm trying to figure out which executable is listening to which IP address and which port on a given machine.

Other than rummaging through each windows service's obscure configuration files, is there a system tool that can more easily give me the details I want?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Very helpful indeed. A friend also introduced me to a freeware utility called Active Ports from DeviceLock http://www.devicelock.com/freeware.html

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As already mentioned [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) by SysInternals (i.e. Microsoft) is a great tool.
But on production systems you may not be allowed to install additional software, so I think you may want to try out netstat.exe, which is typically located at C:\WINNT\system32\netstat.exe .

A help page is available with

```
netstat -?
```

Examples are:

```
netstat -a
```

Lists all local TCP connections and listening ports together with remote TCP endpoint.

```
netstat -o
```

Adds the process ID to the output.

```
netstat -b
```

Gives you the name of the executable wich was involved in establishing this connection/port.

Comment: You still have not have access to it; however, at least the newer versions of TCPView is not an installer, it is a standalone.

Comment: TCPView is a great tool, i've found out that skype listen on the port #80

Answer (score 9):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

SysInternals TCPView is great

Answer (score 3):

Give this a whirl.

```
netstat -abn
```

Answer (score 0):

Command line netstat tool might help you. To learn available parameters run it with /?: netstat /?

Or there is a better GUI alternative: SysInternals TcpView (freely downloadable from ms site)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. Very helpful indeed. A friend also introduced me to a freeware utility called "Active Ports" from DeviceLock: http://www.devicelock.com/freeware.html/